# Plural von "Spatz": "Spatzen" und "Spätze"

Tags: regional, grammatical-number, declension

Das Wort *Spatz* hat (mindestens) zwei Bedeutungen:

- der umgangssprachliche Name des Vogels **Sperling**
- ein **Kosename** für Kind, Partnerin, Partner, etc.

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Spatz) (sowohl online als auch Druckausgabe) und [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Spatz) listen für beide Bedeutungen den Plural ***Spatzen*** auf. Dass der Plural des Vogels *Spatzen* lautet, stelle ich nicht in Frage. Aber mir kommt es ungewöhnlich vor, *Spatzen* auch als Plural des Kosenamens zu verwenden. Hier würde ich intuitiv zum Wort ***Spätze*** greifen.
Bei einer kleinen Internet-Recherche fand ich [im englischen Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Spatz#Etymology_2), dass der Plural des Kosewortes analogisch zum Reimwort *Schätze* *Spätze* laute. Auf der [Diskussionsseite des deutschen Wiktionarys](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Diskussion:Spatz) behauptet ein Schreiber ähnliches. [Beide Einträge stammen nicht von mir]. Googelt man nach *"meine Spätze"* oder *"Dreckspätze"* findet man ein paar hundert Ergebnisse.

Um meine Frage herunterzubrechen auf eine konkrete Situation:
Man stelle sich eine Mutter vor, die Zwillinge bekommen hat und *Spatz* als Kosename verwenden möchte. Welche Variante wird die Mutter dann eher wählen:

> Ihr seid meine **Spatzen**.

oder

> Ihr seid meine **Spätze**.

?

(Falls es eine Rolle spielt: Gibt es regionale Unterschiede?)

Comment: Warum soll die Sprache für Mütter Ausnahmen machen? Und hat nicht der Kosename nicht die Vögel zum Ursprung, wie Mäuschen?

Comment: Gerade in Zusammensetzungen wie _Dreckspatz_ wird deutlich, dass du recht hast: _Dreckspätze_ ist die einzige Form, die sich für mich richtig anhört (und da ich Muttersprachler bin, heißt das – ganz ohne Größenwahn – zwangsläufig, dass es zumindest eine akzeptable Form ist), auch wenn mir das Wort hier rot unterstrichen wird. Es ist auch völlig normal, dass sich scheinbare Homonyme in mindestens einer Form des Paradigmas unterscheiden (können).

Comment: @Crissov "Dreckspätze" hört sich für mich noch falscher an als "Spätze", und die Zahl der Google-Treffer für die beiden Begriffe spricht auch für "Dreckspatzen". Aber vielleicht gibt es da auch regionale Prägungen - wo kommt ihr her? Abgesehen davon: Kosenamen soll jeder gebrauchen, wie er will. Ich habe auch meine Antwort entsprechend erweitert.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich behaupte nicht, dass für Mütter andere Sprachregeln gelten als für den Rest.^^ Ich wollte meine Frage nur auf ein anschauliches Beispiel runterkochen. :-)

Comment: Eine Frage in die Runde: Wofür gab es die Downvotes? [Ist es bei Stack Exchange ein Downvote-Grund, der (implizierten) Annahme einer Frage nicht zuzustimmen?]

Comment: Das Minus gibt es von mir. Man schaut in den Duden und findet den richtigen Plural. Eine zweite Quelle bestätigt es. Trotzig beharrtst Du auf dem Wunsch nach etwas anderem. Welche Evidenz spricht für Deinen Wunsch? Eine ausgedachte Mutter mit Zwillingen, die die Mehrzahl von "Spatz" nicht kennt, also bischen doof ist? Oder wieso sollte sie "Spätze" verwenden wollen, wenn es der Duden nicht kennt? Spatz ist jetzt auch kein neues Wort, bei dem sich ein Plural erst finden muss.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich beharre nicht trotzig, sondern wollte mir eine dritte Meinung von Sprechern einholen, weil die Wörterbuchangabe meinem eigenen Sprachgefühl entgegensteht. Die "doofe Mutter" ist potentiell meine, weshalb ich dieser Aussage widerspreche.

Comment: @userunknown Laß mich Klartext reden: jemanden, und sei es auch eine hypothetische Person, als "bischen doof" [sic!] zu bezeichnen, weil sie einen bestimmten Plural nicht kennt, [is not nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: Spätze hab ich noch nie gehört, das ist kein Deutsch.

Comment: @Matthias: Lt. Duden bedeutet 'doof' 'einfältig und beschränkt'. Genau das wollte ich ausdrücken, ob es nun nett ist oder nicht - da es sich an eine hypothetische Person richtet kann niemand beleidigt sein, außer ein Möchtegernopfer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich sehe keinen Grund, warum der Duden hier nicht Recht haben sollte. Auf die Schnelle fällt mir auch kein anderes Wort ein, das 1:1 als Kosename gebraucht werden kann, aber einen anderen Plural bildet als der Ursprung. Als Alternative zu "Spatzen" käme noch der Diminutiv in Frage: [Spätzchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Spaetzchen).

Andererseits: wo, wenn nicht beim Ersinnen von Kosenamen, herrscht Freiheit im Umgang mit der Sprache? Da wird mit der Sprache gespielt und auch mal eine Regel gebrochen. Von daher:

> Welche Variante wird die Mutter dann eher wählen?

Die, die ihre Gefühle gegenüber ihren Kindern am besten zum Ausdruck bringt. Und wenn das "Spätze" ist, dann ist es das zwar falsch hinsichtlich der Normen der Grammatik, aber trotzdem richtig in Bezug auf den Zweck, dem Sprache letztlich dient: zu kommunizieren und sich mitzuteilen.

Comment: Würdest du selbst für "meine Lieblinge" "meine Spatzen" verwenden?

Comment: @Chris: Wieso sollte man mehr Recht haben, wenn man das Wort selbst verwendet?

Comment: +1 für den Diminutiv - ich denke so wird es meist gemacht (im Schwabenland sowieso "mein/e Schätzle/Spätzle").

Comment: @Chris Nun ja, Kosenamen sind für mich etwas individuelles und von daher eher Singular, "Spatz" wäre da auch nicht meine erste Wahl, und ich würde, wenn schon, zum Diminutiv tendieren. Aber abgesehen davon: ja, auf jeden Fall.

Comment: @userunknown: Wenn ein Wort verwendet wird, dann ist es ja (aus deskriptiver Sicht) eine gültige Variante. Wenn man sich nur auf eine Autorität (hier: Duden) beruft, hat das für mich weniger Gewicht, als wenn man aus erster Hand sagen kann: "Wird so verwendet." - Nun hat Matthias letzteres ja in den Kommentaren nachgeholt, womit ich zufrieden bin: Plural "Spatzen" als Kosewort wird also - entgegen meiner anfänglichen Annahme - verwendet.

Comment: @Chris: Ich kann Dir 1000 Stellen zeigen, wo die Leute seid/seit falsch verwenden und es wird dadurch nicht richtig. Wenn man fragt was richtig ist macht es keinen Sinn sich auf sporadische Fehler als abweichende Kultur zu berufen - dann brauchst Du die Frage nicht stellen sondern benutzt trotzig was Du willst und fertig. Die Aufnahme von Kosenamen in den Duden zeigt, dass die Annahne, diesen seien etwas Individuelles Unfug ist. Dazu kommt, dass Spatz als Kosename sich auf das Tier bezieht und folglich so geschrieben wird, und dass der Plural auch so gebildet wird. Selbst wenn Dein Kosewort...

Comment: "Mobiltelefon" wäre, was individuell wäre, wäre der Plural absehbar "Mobiltelefone" und nicht "Mobilteleföne".

Comment: @Matthias: Was bringt Dich auf die Idee Kossenamen seien etwas individuelles? Wieso stehen sie dann im Duden? Gibt es Beispiele, dass die Pluralbildung für Individuelles von der Pluralbildung sonst abweicht, oder wieso soll das ein Argument sein? Mein Upvote musste ich für diese *Verbesserung* in ein Minus verwandeln. Fragen danach, was richtig ist, sind so zu beantworten, dass der Deutschlehrer sie nicht ankreiden würde, auch wenn man selbst aus der Schule raus ist.

Comment: @userunknown: Für mich gibt's da einen Unterschied zwischen Spatzen/Spätze und seid/seit: Bei letzterem geht's um Rechtschreibung, bei ersterem um Formenlehre. Ich wäre bereit, "Mobilteleföne" als korrekte Variante anzusehen, wenn es denn nicht nur individuell verwendet wird (und werfe noch ein "Mobiltelefons" in die Runde). ("Spätze" wird übrigens nicht nur von mir verwendet, sondern wenn man nach "meine Spätze" und "Dreckspätze" googelt, gibt es dutzende Treffer.) - Was ich aus der Frage mitnehme: (Auch) "Spatzen" wird als Plural des Kosewortes verwendet. Das hätte ich anfangs nicht gedacht.

Comment: @userunknown "individuell" meinte ich im Sinne von "auf eine einzelne Person bezogen". Chris hatte mich nach meinem persönlichen Verhalten in einer hypothetischen Situation gefragt, und ich wollte zum Ausdruck bringen, daß ich das nur eingeschränkt beantworten kann, weil ich den selben Kosenamen eher nicht für zwei Personen verwenden würde und mir deshalb nur schwer Bedarf für einen Plural vorstellen kann. Das später von Crissov angesprochene "Dreckspatzen" ist für mich in diesem Sinne kein Kosename mehr. Das würde ich auch so im Plural gebrauchen.

Comment: @userunknown Es handelt sich hier gar nicht um eine "Frage danach, was richtig ist", wie Du behauptest. Chris hat ziemlich eindeutig danach gefragt, welche Version tatsächlich verwendet wird. Und nach meinem Eindruck hat er eine zufriedenstellende Antwort bekommen. Abgesehen davon war es mir auch wichtig, deutlich zu machen, daß es Bereiche des Sprachgebrauchs gibt, in denen die Sicht des Deutschlehrers nicht die allein maßgebliche Instanz ist. Kosenamen gehören für mich dazu, Lyrik wäre ein weiteres Beispiel.

Answer (score 1):

Nachdem auch regionale Unterschiede nachgefragt wurden:

Zur Situation in Österreich (zumindest Ost-Österreich):

Die Form »Spätze« habe ich noch nie gehört. In Fall der Vögel steht das Paar »*der Spatz,  die Spatzen*« ohnehin außer Streit.

Doch auch als Kosenamen kenne ich nur dieses Paar:

> der Spatz, die Spatzen

Als Kosename wird in Österreich aber bevorzugt das österreichische Diminutiv (gebildet durch Anfügen der Endsilbe *-erl*) verwendet, und davon auch der Plural gebildet:

> das Spatzerl, die Spatzerln

Dabei ist auch zu erwähnen, dass »*das Spatzerl*« neuerdings (seit grob geschätzten 20 Jahren) auch als Synonym für den Penis verwendet wird, weswegen die Verwendung als Kosename aus der Mode gekommen ist. (Die Verwendung als Synonym für *Penis* geht auf den österreichischen Karikaturisten Manfred Deix zurück, ähnlich wie *Schniedelwutz* auf Otto Waalkes zurückgeführt werden kann)